# Find the overlapping area between two squares, where one is moved and tilted at the angle $a$

Tags: geometry

Consider a square whose side is $a$.
Now consider another square whose side is also $a$ but it's **moved to the right** by $\frac{a}{2}$ in respect to the first square, and then **rotated around the center of the first square** by $\phi$ counterclockwise.

I would like for a formula to calculate the overlapping area between the two squares in respect to $a$ and $\phi$

An [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2990.png) illustrating the area when $\phi = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

---

**My attempts** have only yielded solutions for some points, but not for $\phi\in[0,2\pi)$ which is what I'm aiming for.

For $\phi\in\{0, \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}\}$ computing the area is quite trivial because it's just $\frac{a^2}{2}$.

For $\phi\in\{\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4}\}$ I came up with the following:

> We can divide the overlapping area into a rectangle $ab$ and right isosceles triangle whose catheti are equal to $x$. ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MunHG.png))
>
> To find $b$, inscribe a circle inside the first square. If we let $D=a\sqrt{2}$ be the diagonal of the square and $r=\frac{a}{2}$ be the radius of the circle, note that $b = D/2 - r$ because it forms an right isosceles triangle with the side $a$.
>   $$\begin{align}
> ab &= a\cdot (D/2 - r)\\ 
> &=\frac{a^2}{2}(\sqrt{2} - 1)
> \end{align}$$
>
> Let $z=b\sqrt{2}$ be the hypotenuse of that smaller right isosceles triangle. Now cathetus of the original triangle we were looking for is $x = a-z$ and the area of that triangle is $\frac{x^2}{2}$.
>   $$\begin{align}
> x&=a-z \\
> &= a - b\sqrt2\\
> &=a - \frac{a}{2}(\sqrt2 - 1)\sqrt2\\
> &=\frac{a\sqrt{2}}{2} \rightarrow \frac{x^2}{2} = \frac{a^2}{4}
> \end{align}$$ 
>   The total area is then: $ab + \frac{x^2}{2} = \frac{a^2}{2}(\sqrt2 - \frac34)$

Although I feel this could've been a lot simpler and if I have made an error on the way please correct me.

Now how do I find the area for any $\phi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula
$$
f(\phi)=\frac{a^2}{4}
\left(
\tan(\tfrac\phi2)+\tan(\tfrac\pi4-\tfrac\phi2)
+
\tfrac12\left(1+\tan(\tfrac\phi2)\right)\cdot\left(1+\tan(\tfrac\pi4-\tfrac\phi2)\right)
\right)
$$
appears to do the job for $\phi\in[0,\pi/2]$. It can easily be extended to all rotation angles, since the overlaps repeat due to symmetry every $\pi/2$.

---

### Explanation

Consider the following figure, and assume for now the side of the square is $2$ so that the circle is a unit circle:

[image]

We are trying to determine the area of the pentagon $KDEGJ$. In order to do this, we can sum $\square KDEJ$ and $\Delta EGJ$. We have the tilt angle $\phi=\angle FCD$ with complementary angle $\frac\pi2-\phi=\angle KCH$. From this and using the symmetry of tangents to a circle, one can deduce that
$$
\begin{align}
DE&=EF=\tan(\tfrac\phi2)\\
HJ&=JK=\tan(\tfrac\pi4-\tfrac\phi2)
\end{align}
$$
so that we have (noting that $KD=2$)
$$
\square KDEJ=\tan(\tfrac\phi2)+\tan(\tfrac\pi4-\tfrac\phi2)
$$
Furthermore it follows that
$$
\begin{align}
EG&=1+\tan(\tfrac\phi2)\\
GJ&=1+\tan(\tfrac\pi4-\tfrac\phi2)
\end{align}
$$
and so
$$
\Delta EGJ=\tfrac12\left(1+\tan(\tfrac\phi2)\right)\cdot\left(1+\tan(\tfrac\pi4-\tfrac\phi2)\right)
$$

The factor $a^2/2^2$ in front is simply a rescaling from side length $2$ to an arbitrary side length $a$ of the square.